# How to retrieve values from json data response using regex regulations?

Tags: c#, json, regex

Am having difficult to read my regex matches according to what i received back from response. Anyone can guide me on how regex could work for the following json format?

```
 HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            myReq.ContentType = "application/json";

            // here's how to set response content type:
            Response.ContentType = "application/json"; // that's all

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();
            string text;

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                text = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

            MatchCollection nameCollection = Regex.Matches(text, @"<_id>\s*(.+?)\s*</_id>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
            MatchCollection postalCollection = Regex.Matches(text, @"<postal_code>\s*(.+?)\s*</postal_code>", RegexOptions.Singleline)
            MatchCollection schoolCollection= Regex.Matches(text, @"<all_schools_2016>\s*(.+?)\s*</postal_code>,", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

**text**

> {"help":
>   "https://data.gov.sg/api/3/action/help_show?name=datastore_search",
>   "success": true, "result": {"resource_id":
>   "36e6b5fc-9acc-4344-8f5f-5f67d52c525f", "fields": [{"type": "int4",
>   "id": "_id"}, {"type": "text", "id": "all_schools_2016"}, {"type":
>   "text", "id": "address"}, {"type": "numeric", "id": "postal_code"}],
>   "records": [{"_id": 1, "postal_code": "738907", "all_schools_2016":
>   "ADMIRALTY PRIMARY SCHOOL", "address": "11 WOODLANDS CIRCLE"}, {"_id":
>   2, "postal_code": "737916", "all_schools_2016": "ADMIRALTY SECONDARY
>   SCHOOL", "address": "31 WOODLANDS CRESCENT"}, {"_id": 3,
>   "postal_code": "768643", "all_schools_2016": "AHMAD IBRAHIM PRIMARY
>   SCHOOL", "address": "10 YISHUN STREET 11"}, {"_id": 4, "postal_code":
>   "768928", "all_schools_2016": "AHMAD IBRAHIM SECONDARY SCHOOL",
>   "address": "751 YISHUN AVENUE 7"}, {"_id": 5, "postal_code": "579646",
>   "all_schools_2016": "AI TONG SCHOOL", "address": "100 Bright Hill
>   Drive"}], "_links": {"start":
>   "/api/action/datastore_search?limit=5&resource_id=36e6b5fc-9acc-4344-8f5f-5f67d52c525f",
>   "next":
>   "/api/action/datastore_search?offset=5&limit=5&resource_id=36e6b5fc-9acc-4344-8f5f-5f67d52c525f"},
>   "limit": 5, "total": 367}}

Comment: JSON is not an HTML but parsing it with RegEx is still a bad idea.

Comment: Why are you using Regex for parsing JSON?You can directly parse those values.

Comment: What do you mean? the url only gives me partial data i needed, thus i'm using this method to retreive data

Comment: Why not to use Json.NET with SelectToken? http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm

Comment: What results are you getting and what results do you want to get. Please read [mcve] then update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need a regular expression for this task?

Using [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

```
string json = "...";
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
if((bool)data.success)
{
     IEnumerable<dynamic> records = data.result.records;

     IEnumerable<int> names = records.Select(r => (int)r._id);
     IEnumerable<string> postal = records.Select(r => (string)r.postal_code);
     IEnumerable<string> schools = records.Select(r => (string)r.all_schools_2016);
}
```